# HTML support in phtml file

Tags: visual-studio-code

When working with pthml file, how do I get the HTML-Intellisense like I got when working with html file?

I have the extension PHP Intelephense installed, but it's not recommending the closing tag when adding new HTML tag. Or did I configured something wrongly?

Edited:
VS Code can do this by altering the setting file association. So if I associate the phtml file with html, I get the Intellisense for html, and the same for php. I think what I really want is to associate phtml with html and php... which is impossible for now, I guess.

For reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22415

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you provide a code snippet? What part was working that isn't working anymore?

Comment: Is the extension .phtml ?

Comment: @Mark yes, I'm talking about .phtml file

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.phtml": "html"
}
```

in your settings file.  This should give .phtml files the same intellisense as html files.

Comment: But doing this means I would lose the Intellisense for PHP inside phtml file. Is there any way so that I can have Intellisense for both PHP and HTML? Afterall, phtml is php+html.